# Turn text field into input field and back again

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, input

So I'm trying to make it so every time you click on a text field, it turns into an input field, then you type whatever you want, click enter, it turns back into a text field, and the process starts all over again. I was able to get it to run, but only once. How can I make this run multiple times, so I can keep changing the text value?

```
<p class="text">Text</p>

$(".text").click(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith("<input type='text' class='text'>");
  $(".text").select();

  $(".text").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      var textVal = $(".text").val();
      $(".text").replaceWith("<p class='text'>" + textVal + "</p>");
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here's the code:

```
<p class="text">Text</p>

function changeText() {
  $(".text").click(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith("<input type='text' class='text'>");
    $(".text").select();

    $(".text").keypress(function(e) {
      if (e.which == 13) {
        var textVal = $(".text").val();
        $(".text").replaceWith("<p class='text'>" + textVal + "</p>");
        changeText();
      }
    });

  });
}

changeText();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better

```js
$(function() {
    $(".text").live("click", function() {
        // alert(7);
        $(this).replaceWith("<input type='text'/>");

        $("input").live("blur", function() {
            var textVal = $("input").val();
            $("input").replaceWith("<p class='text'>" + textVal + "</p>");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Try to include some explanation to improve your answer better

Comment: No worries. We come here to learn. Not only we learn programming stuffs but also how to communicate effectively. Give it a try :)

Comment: I am this year just contact of programming, but my English is very bad

Comment: That's ok. All the best! :D